# Ubuntu constantly switching between 2.4 and 5Ghz access points

Tags: networking, wireless

I have an issue where my wifi is constantly dropping out every few seconds. I investigated and it seems like it is repeatedly switching between my 2.4 and 5Ghz access points. Here's the log from `dmesg`:

```
[89032.530655] wlp4s0: associated
[89032.965603] wlp4s0: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by 9c:69:d1:c4:40:d5
[89049.876628] wlp4s0: Connection to AP 9c:69:d1:c4:40:d5 lost
[89051.068203] wlp4s0: authenticate with 9c:69:d1:c4:40:d4
[89051.070021] wlp4s0: send auth to 9c:69:d1:c4:40:d4 (try 1/3)
[89051.096029] wlp4s0: authenticated
[89051.099922] wlp4s0: associate with 9c:69:d1:c4:40:d4 (try 1/3)
[89051.103659] wlp4s0: RX AssocResp from 9c:69:d1:c4:40:d4 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[89051.108251] wlp4s0: associated
[89055.223602] wlp4s0: disconnect from AP 9c:69:d1:c4:40:d4 for new auth to 9c:69:d1:c4:40:d5
[89055.226707] wlp4s0: authenticate with 9c:69:d1:c4:40:d5
[89055.228727] wlp4s0: send auth to 9c:69:d1:c4:40:d5 (try 1/3)
[89055.255620] wlp4s0: authenticated
[89055.255947] wlp4s0: associate with 9c:69:d1:c4:40:d5 (try 1/3)
[89055.256970] wlp4s0: RX ReassocResp from 9c:69:d1:c4:40:d5 (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=1)
[89055.264991] wlp4s0: associated
[89055.493829] wlp4s0: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by 9c:69:d1:c4:40:d5
[89062.984360] wlp4s0: Connection to AP 9c:69:d1:c4:40:d5 lost
[89063.201360] wlp4s0: authenticate with 9c:69:d1:c4:40:d4
[89063.204176] wlp4s0: send auth to 9c:69:d1:c4:40:d4 (try 1/3)
[89063.234594] wlp4s0: authenticated
[89063.236037] wlp4s0: associate with 9c:69:d1:c4:40:d4 (try 1/3)
[89063.241114] wlp4s0: RX AssocResp from 9c:69:d1:c4:40:d4 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[89063.246862] wlp4s0: associated
[89065.489145] wlp4s0: disconnect from AP 9c:69:d1:c4:40:d4 for new auth to 9c:69:d1:c4:40:d5
[89065.492204] wlp4s0: authenticate with 9c:69:d1:c4:40:d5
[89065.494245] wlp4s0: send auth to 9c:69:d1:c4:40:d5 (try 1/3)
[89065.522102] wlp4s0: authenticated
[89065.524058] wlp4s0: associate with 9c:69:d1:c4:40:d5 (try 1/3)
[89065.535076] wlp4s0: RX ReassocResp from 9c:69:d1:c4:40:d5 (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=1)
[89065.536913] wlp4s0: associated
[89065.631303] wlp4s0: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by 9c:69:d1:c4:40:d5
[89075.682628] wlp4s0: Connection to AP 9c:69:d1:c4:40:d5 lost
[89075.856175] wlp4s0: Connection to AP 00:00:00:00:00:00 lost
[89076.583517] wlp4s0: authenticate with 9c:69:d1:c4:40:d4
[89076.585590] wlp4s0: send auth to 9c:69:d1:c4:40:d4 (try 1/3)
[89076.612634] wlp4s0: authenticated
[89076.616164] wlp4s0: associate with 9c:69:d1:c4:40:d4 (try 1/3)
[89076.620538] wlp4s0: RX AssocResp from 9c:69:d1:c4:40:d4 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[89076.625083] wlp4s0: associated
```

The internet connection stops working every time it says `Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by 9c:69:d1:c4:40:d5` and starts working again when it says `associated`.

`sudo iwlist wlp4s0 scan` shows that `9c:69:d1:c4:40:d4` is my 2.4Ghz and `9c:69:d1:c4:40:d5` is my 5Ghz access point.

I have an Intel ax200 pcie wifi card. It could also be some sort of issue with power saving? (the limiting tx power?)

Comment: It's always recommend to have different SSIDs for the "same" 2.4GHz and 5GHz AP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your wireless may be dropping because of power management; that is, the feature where the card partially powers down to save battery power during periods of inactivity and then, ideally, powers back up seamlessly when activity resumes. Let's disable power saving to see if it helps. From the terminal:

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
```

Your wireless may be dropping because the channel to which it was connected has suddenly changed.

Please check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I recommend a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred.

Your wireless may be dropping because there are two wireless access points with the same name and password. This is typical when you have a 2.4 gHz segment and a 5 gHz segment of the same router. Your wireless may be roaming, looking for a better connection. If this is the case, I suggest that you rename the access points; something like myrouter2.4 and myrouter5.

After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Is there any improvement?