# Ubuntu 23.10 wifi connects and disconnects every few seconds with 0bda:c811 Realtek adapter

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, realtek, 23.10

I am attempting to dual boot Ubuntu 23.10 with Windows 10. When I boot into Ubuntu the Wifi connects and then disconnects a few seconds later. It does this constantly.

At first, after I had installed Ubuntu, the Wifi didn't connect at all. To fix this I installed a driver **morrownr/8821cu-20210916** from github. The Wifi worked for a few hours before it started connecting and disconnecting every few seconds. I've rebooted it many times and tried reinstalling the driver but it hasn't worked.

**Attempted Fixes:**

- I have disabled fast boot on Windows 10.
- Moved the Realtek Wifi Adapter to several different ports on the computer
- Disabled ipv6 in the Wifi connections settings
- Blacklisted a selection of other wifi drivers, as recommended as a solution to someone
  elses similar problem

**Possible Problems**

- Sometimes the clock time on Ubuntu and Windows is wrong, I attempted to fix this by setting the time on the hardware clock
- I am not certain that the driver was installed properly. All I did was: download it from github, run the `./install-driver.sh` script and save the default config file. I then ran the command `sudo modprobe 8821cu`

When I run the command `lsusb`, my wifi adapter shows up as `0bda:c811`

Please let me know what command outputs would be useful do diagnose the problem. Thanks, Maverick.

**Edit 1**

The output of `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`:

```
Oct 20 16:26:26 RedUbuntu23 systemd[1]: Starting NetworkManager.service - Network Manager...
Oct 20 16:26:32 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811992.0802] NetworkManager (version 1.44.2) is starting... (boot:3307225c-e534-4246-bbcd-673d440aa300)
Oct 20 16:26:32 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811992.0803] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, 20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf, no-mac-addr-change.conf) (run: 10-globally-managed-devices.conf) (etc: default-wifi-powersave-on.conf)
Oct 20 16:26:32 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811992.2247] manager[0x563f3960a720]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Oct 20 16:26:32 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811992.2248] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Oct 20 16:26:32 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811992.4380] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Oct 20 16:26:32 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811992.4381] hostname: static hostname changed from (none) to "RedUbuntu23"
Oct 20 16:26:32 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811992.4394] dns-mgr: init: dns=systemd-resolved rc-manager=unmanaged (auto), plugin=systemd-resolved
Oct 20 16:26:32 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811992.4414] rfkill0: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill0) (driver rtw_8821cu)
Oct 20 16:26:32 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811992.4416] manager[0x563f3960a720]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
Oct 20 16:26:32 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811992.4416] manager[0x563f3960a720]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Oct 20 16:26:32 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811992.6269] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.44.2/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
Oct 20 16:26:32 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811992.7878] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.44.2/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
Oct 20 16:26:32 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811992.8575] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.44.2/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
Oct 20 16:26:32 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811992.9587] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.44.2/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Oct 20 16:26:32 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811992.9593] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.44.2/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
Oct 20 16:26:32 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811992.9596] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Oct 20 16:26:32 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811992.9596] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Oct 20 16:26:32 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811992.9596] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Oct 20 16:26:33 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811993.1377] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.44.2/libnm-settings-plugin-ifupdown.so")
Oct 20 16:26:33 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811993.1378] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
Oct 20 16:26:33 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811993.1378] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Oct 20 16:26:33 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811993.2152] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
Oct 20 16:26:36 RedUbuntu23 generate[1217]: Permissions for /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml are too open. Netplan configuration should NOT be accessible by others.
Oct 20 16:26:36 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811996.4790] dhcp: init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
Oct 20 16:26:36 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811996.4793] manager: (lo): new Loopback device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Oct 20 16:26:36 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811996.4805] device (lo): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 20 16:26:36 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811996.4810] device (lo): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 20 16:26:36 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811996.4817] device (lo): Activation: starting connection 'lo' (aa37dd63-3695-487b-bf81-4911a1f2e46f)
Oct 20 16:26:36 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811996.4829] manager: (enp6s0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Oct 20 16:26:36 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811996.4831] device (enp6s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 20 16:26:36 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811996.7318] device (wlx502b73a9677b): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Oct 20 16:26:36 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811996.7324] manager: (wlx502b73a9677b): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Oct 20 16:26:36 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697811996.7326] device (wlx502b73a9677b): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 20 16:26:48 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812008.5996] failed to open /run/network/ifstate
Oct 20 16:26:48 RedUbuntu23 systemd[1]: Started NetworkManager.service - Network Manager.
Oct 20 16:26:48 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812008.6005] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
Oct 20 16:26:48 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <warn>  [1697812008.6007] dns-mgr: update-pending changed: DNS plugin did not become ready again. Assume something is wrong
Oct 20 16:26:48 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812008.6017] device (lo): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 20 16:26:48 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812008.6020] device (lo): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 20 16:26:48 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812008.6023] device (lo): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 20 16:26:48 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812008.6032] device (lo): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 20 16:26:48 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812008.6037] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Oct 20 16:26:48 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812008.8859] device (lo): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 20 16:26:48 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812008.8861] device (lo): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 20 16:26:48 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812008.8866] device (lo): Activation: successful, device activated.
Oct 20 16:26:49 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812009.4643] device (wlx502b73a9677b): supplicant interface state: internal-starting -> disconnected
Oct 20 16:26:49 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812009.4644] device (wlx502b73a9677b): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 20 16:26:49 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812009.9657] manager: startup complete
Oct 20 16:27:05 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812025.3085] agent-manager: agent[bce397d468451cd2,:1.41/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/123]: agent registered
Oct 20 16:27:11 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812031.4892] policy: auto-activating connection 'BumBleBee25 1' (ead9d6f1-62dc-464f-af93-56505a076904)
Oct 20 16:27:11 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812031.4896] device (wlx502b73a9677b): Activation: starting connection 'BumBleBee25 1' (ead9d6f1-62dc-464f-af93-56505a076904)
Oct 20 16:27:11 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812031.4897] device (wlx502b73a9677b): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 20 16:27:11 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812031.4898] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Oct 20 16:27:11 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812031.4901] device (wlx502b73a9677b): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 20 16:27:11 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812031.4904] device (wlx502b73a9677b): Activation: (wifi) access point 'BumBleBee25 1' has security, but secrets are required.
Oct 20 16:27:11 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812031.4904] device (wlx502b73a9677b): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 20 16:27:11 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812031.4905] sup-iface[1cfe17f38eeebb3f,0,wlx502b73a9677b]: wps: type pbc start...
Oct 20 16:27:11 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812031.4913] device (wlx502b73a9677b): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 20 16:27:11 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812031.4915] device (wlx502b73a9677b): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 20 16:27:11 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812031.4918] device (wlx502b73a9677b): Activation: (wifi) connection 'BumBleBee25 1' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Oct 20 16:27:11 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812031.4962] Config: added 'ssid' value 'BumBleBee25'
Oct 20 16:27:11 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812031.4962] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Oct 20 16:27:11 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812031.4962] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Oct 20 16:27:11 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812031.4962] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
Oct 20 16:27:11 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812031.4962] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Oct 20 16:27:11 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812031.4962] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Oct 20 16:27:23 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812043.1456] agent-manager: agent[aec1fcf77badc551,:1.86/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
Oct 20 16:27:23 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812043.4831] device (wlx502b73a9677b): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
Oct 20 16:27:23 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812043.4853] device (wlx502b73a9677b): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Oct 20 16:27:24 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812044.0714] device (wlx502b73a9677b): supplicant interface state: associating -> completed
Oct 20 16:27:24 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812044.0714] device (wlx502b73a9677b): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "BumBleBee25"
Oct 20 16:27:24 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812044.0715] device (wlx502b73a9677b): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 20 16:27:24 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812044.0721] dhcp4 (wlx502b73a9677b): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Oct 20 16:27:24 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812044.6556] dhcp4 (wlx502b73a9677b): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.103
Oct 20 16:27:24 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812044.6560] policy: set 'BumBleBee25 1' (wlx502b73a9677b) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Oct 20 16:27:24 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812044.6621] device (wlx502b73a9677b): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 20 16:27:24 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812044.7251] device (wlx502b73a9677b): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 20 16:27:24 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812044.7252] device (wlx502b73a9677b): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 20 16:27:24 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812044.7255] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Oct 20 16:27:24 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812044.7258] device (wlx502b73a9677b): Activation: successful, device activated.
Oct 20 16:27:25 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812045.7057] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Oct 20 16:27:28 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812048.6891] dhcp6 (wlx502b73a9677b): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Oct 20 16:28:03 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812083.2414] device (wlx502b73a9677b): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Oct 20 16:28:14 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812094.8997] device (wlx502b73a9677b): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct 20 16:28:18 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <warn>  [1697812098.0170] device (wlx502b73a9677b): link timed out.
Oct 20 16:28:18 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812098.0173] device (wlx502b73a9677b): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 20 16:28:18 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812098.0176] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Oct 20 16:28:18 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <warn>  [1697812098.0180] device (wlx502b73a9677b): Activation: failed for connection 'BumBleBee25 1'
Oct 20 16:28:18 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812098.0185] device (wlx502b73a9677b): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 20 16:28:18 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812098.0191] dhcp4 (wlx502b73a9677b): canceled DHCP transaction
Oct 20 16:28:18 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812098.0191] dhcp4 (wlx502b73a9677b): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Oct 20 16:28:18 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812098.0191] dhcp4 (wlx502b73a9677b): state changed no lease
Oct 20 16:28:18 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812098.0192] dhcp6 (wlx502b73a9677b): canceled DHCP transaction
Oct 20 16:28:18 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812098.0192] dhcp6 (wlx502b73a9677b): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Oct 20 16:28:18 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812098.0192] dhcp6 (wlx502b73a9677b): state changed no lease
Oct 20 16:28:25 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812105.2901] device (wlx502b73a9677b): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Oct 20 16:28:25 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812105.2902] policy: auto-activating connection 'BumBleBee25 1' (ead9d6f1-62dc-464f-af93-56505a076904)
Oct 20 16:28:25 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812105.2907] device (wlx502b73a9677b): Activation: starting connection 'BumBleBee25 1' (ead9d6f1-62dc-464f-af93-56505a076904)
Oct 20 16:28:25 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812105.2908] device (wlx502b73a9677b): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 20 16:28:25 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812105.2911] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Oct 20 16:28:25 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812105.2913] device (wlx502b73a9677b): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 20 16:28:25 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812105.2916] device (wlx502b73a9677b): Activation: (wifi) access point 'BumBleBee25 1' has security, but secrets are required.
Oct 20 16:28:25 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812105.2916] device (wlx502b73a9677b): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 20 16:28:25 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812105.2918] sup-iface[1cfe17f38eeebb3f,0,wlx502b73a9677b]: wps: type pbc start...
Oct 20 16:28:25 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812105.2927] device (wlx502b73a9677b): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 20 16:28:25 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812105.2930] device (wlx502b73a9677b): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 20 16:28:25 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812105.2932] device (wlx502b73a9677b): Activation: (wifi) connection 'BumBleBee25 1' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Oct 20 16:28:25 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812105.2933] Config: added 'ssid' value 'BumBleBee25'
Oct 20 16:28:25 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812105.2933] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Oct 20 16:28:25 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812105.2933] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Oct 20 16:28:25 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812105.2934] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
Oct 20 16:28:25 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812105.2934] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Oct 20 16:28:25 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812105.2934] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Oct 20 16:28:37 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812117.2707] device (wlx502b73a9677b): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
Oct 20 16:28:37 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812117.8812] device (wlx502b73a9677b): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Oct 20 16:28:38 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812118.2256] device (wlx502b73a9677b): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Oct 20 16:28:42 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812122.2122] device (wlx502b73a9677b): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
Oct 20 16:28:42 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812122.4556] device (wlx502b73a9677b): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
Oct 20 16:28:42 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812122.4556] device (wlx502b73a9677b): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "BumBleBee25"
Oct 20 16:28:42 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812122.4558] device (wlx502b73a9677b): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 20 16:28:42 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812122.4564] dhcp4 (wlx502b73a9677b): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Oct 20 16:28:42 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812122.7673] dhcp4 (wlx502b73a9677b): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.103
Oct 20 16:28:42 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812122.7678] policy: set 'BumBleBee25 1' (wlx502b73a9677b) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Oct 20 16:28:42 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812122.8245] device (wlx502b73a9677b): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 20 16:28:42 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812122.8646] device (wlx502b73a9677b): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 20 16:28:42 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812122.8648] device (wlx502b73a9677b): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 20 16:28:42 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812122.8652] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Oct 20 16:28:42 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812122.8658] device (wlx502b73a9677b): Activation: successful, device activated.
Oct 20 16:28:43 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812123.8034] dhcp6 (wlx502b73a9677b): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Oct 20 16:29:12 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812152.2770] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Oct 20 16:29:41 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812181.1584] device (wlx502b73a9677b): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
```

The output of service NetworkManager status:

```
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-10-20 16:26:48 SAST; 3min 47s ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 1100 (NetworkManager)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 19032)
     Memory: 18.1M
        CPU: 511ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
             └─1100 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

Oct 20 16:30:15 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812215.6522] dhcp4 (wlx502b73a9677b): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Oct 20 16:30:15 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812215.7863] dhcp4 (wlx502b73a9677b): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.103
Oct 20 16:30:15 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812215.7867] policy: set 'BumBleBee25 1' (wlx502b73a9677b) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Oct 20 16:30:15 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812215.8475] device (wlx502b73a9677b): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 20 16:30:15 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812215.8925] device (wlx502b73a9677b): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 20 16:30:15 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812215.8927] device (wlx502b73a9677b): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 20 16:30:15 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812215.8931] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Oct 20 16:30:15 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812215.8938] device (wlx502b73a9677b): Activation: successful, device activated.
Oct 20 16:30:16 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812216.9896] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Oct 20 16:30:17 RedUbuntu23 NetworkManager[1100]: <info>  [1697812217.7924] dhcp6 (wlx502b73a9677b): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
```

The output of service --status-all:

```
 [ - ]  anacron
 [ + ]  apparmor
 [ + ]  apport
 [ - ]  bluetooth
 [ - ]  console-setup.sh
 [ + ]  cron
 [ + ]  cups
 [ + ]  dbus
 [ + ]  gdm3
 [ - ]  grub-common
 [ - ]  hwclock.sh
 [ + ]  irqbalance
 [ + ]  kerneloops
 [ - ]  keyboard-setup.sh
 [ + ]  kmod
 [ + ]  openvpn
 [ - ]  plymouth
 [ + ]  plymouth-log
 [ + ]  procps
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ - ]  saned
 [ - ]  speech-dispatcher
 [ - ]  spice-vdagent
 [ - ]  sssd
 [ + ]  udev
 [ + ]  ufw
 [ + ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  uuidd
 [ - ]  whoopsie
 [ - ]  x11-common
```

**Attempted Fixes:**

- I ran `sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*` to try and turn the wifi off of power saver mode, it did not solve my problem unfortunately
- I used `sudo iw reg set ZA` to set the regulatory domain. When I tried to run
  `sudo nano /etc/default/crda` it created a new file instead of finding the file, so I didn't do anything there

Comment: Please consider my troubleshooting steps here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333427/ubuntu-constantly-switching-between-2-4-and-5ghz-access-points/1333497#1333497  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.

Comment: Hi, I edited my original post to add the outputs of the commands suggested by waltinator and to describe some of the fixes from chili555s post. Unfortunately they didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: I disabled ipv6 of the network and restarted the PC. This led to the wifi working properly for about 10 minutes before reverting to constantly disconnecting and reconnecting. 
@chili555

Comment: I have the same problem since upgrading to 23.10 a few days ago. My brcmfmac driver query says the device is wlp3s0 and when I  'sudo dmesg | grep -i wlp3s0' I can see repeated every few seconds "brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0" but I don't know where to start.

Comment: @darth_epoxy Please start your own new question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this in your Settings? If so turn it off.

[image: Connectivity Checking in Settings]

Comment: I found this setting and disabled it. I restarted my PC and also ran `sudo service NetworkManager restart`, but unfortunately my wifi still disconnects constantly.